# Is There a Way to Make a Mainstream Code Editor Treat the Contents of a Database Field as if it were a Code File?

Tags: sql-server, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, notepad++

I'm working with a scriptable CAD/CAM system that runs on Windows 10 whose built-in code pane is not very useful.  The user-defined scripting code for this CAD/CAM system is not saved in text files, but rather, in a field in an SQL Server.  I'm thinking there might be some way of setting up Visual Studio/VSCode (or maybe Notepad++) to work with the code in the database the same way it would do if were in a text file.  I could probably set up some sort of .Net FileSystemWatcher utility that keeps a bunch of code files it sees in a directory synched with code in the SQL Server data field.  But I have deadlines, and I'm supposed to be scripting this CAD/CAM system--not building tools to script the CAD/CAM system.  Any ideas for a "quick fix"?

Comment: see if somebody has written a remote file system VSC extension for an SQL Database, unlikely because it has nothing uniform, you have to write it yourself

Comment: You can probably quickly throw together a powershell script that updates table field from a file once in a while. Then you can edit the file in your favourite editor